# Difference between using double quotes, single quotes or none with grep

Tags: shell, grep

I want to know whats the difference between look for a character with grep command with doble quotes, single quotes or none e.g.

`grep ^'\' foo`

`grep ^"\" foo`

`grep \ foo`

Comment: Did you run those? Note anything weird with the last two? (Also, `grep` is of no consequence here, you could try the same with `echo` instead.)

Comment: It's not about grep, it's about shell. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: This thread is useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/69283/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-or-no-quotes-in-grep

Answer (score 1):

You actually produced a bad example with the `\` and putting the `^` outside the quotes.

The behavior of the quotes (or their absence) is determined by the shell that you use (I am assuming `bash`), and not by `grep`.  As a general rule of thumb:

```
"  double quotes      Shell variables between the quotes are expanded
'  single quote       Shell variables do not get expanded
   no quotes          you can only use a single word, unless you escape the spaces.
```

So, keep in mind that the shell first does some interpretation, and then passes the arguments to `grep`.

Now some examples:

```
cat >afile <<EOF
a
aa
aaa
EOF
cat > abfile <<EOF
a
b
ab
aba
EOF
avar=a
```

We create two files `afile` and `abfile` and a shell variable `avar`.

`grep 'a' afile` will give:

```
a
aa
aaa
```

`grep "a" afile` will give:

```
a
aa
aaa
```

(the same). `grep "$avar" afile` will expand the variable `avar` to `a` and therefore, the result is

```
a
aa
aaa
```

However, `grep '$avar' afile` does not expand the variable `avar`, and therefore the result is:

(empty)

The abfile was created for the example without quotes. You should now understand why:

```
avar='a abfile'
grep $avar
```

gives:

```
a
ab
aba
```

Of course, if you want to find single quotes, you should `grep "'"` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Any shell "word" consisting of quoted strings butted together is still a single argument. So you can make arguments out of parts with different rules.

```
Paul--) Q='One Two'
Paul--) J=A'${Q}'B"${Q}"C
Paul--) echo ::"${J}"::
::A${Q}BOne TwoC::
Paul--) echo ::${J}{Foo,Bar}::
::A${Q}BOne TwoCFoo:: ::A${Q}BOne TwoCBar::
Paul--) echo ::"${J}{Foo,Bar}"::
::A${Q}BOne TwoC{Foo,Bar}::
```